# Cast int as byte array in Java directly / What type of bytes(?) do I want

Tags: java, casting, int, arrays

I want to cast an `int` to a `byte[]` in Java. Can this be done directly? I noticed I can do this by converting it to a string like so:

```
            int num = 5;
            String dataString = Integer.toString(num);
            byte[] data = dataString.getBytes();
```

I was just curious if there was a direct method such as `num.getBytes()`.

I'm doing this in the frame of reference of using the Java Xbee library. In the example they do the following:

```
private static final String DATA_TO_SEND = "Hello XBee World!";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    XBeeDevice myDevice = new XBeeDevice(PORT, BAUD_RATE);
    byte[] dataToSend = DATA_TO_SEND.getBytes();

    try {
        myDevice.open();

        System.out.format("Sending broadcast data: '%s'", new String(dataToSend));

        myDevice.sendBroadcastData(dataToSend);

        System.out.println(" >> Success");

    } catch (XBeeException e) {
        System.out.println(" >> Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        myDevice.close();
    }
}
```

If I had an int how should I send that data? The `sendBroadcastData()` function takes `byte[]` as an argument. The example I'm referring to above can be found [here](https://docs.digi.com/display/XBJLIB/Add+the+application+source+code)

Comment: You can't directly cast. What bytes do you want anyway? The bytes of its two's complement representation?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that your string conversion is doing what you want, btw...

Comment: @fge I'm not sure? I edited the question to show what I'm doing.